# mat-form-field placeholder text misaligned

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

My `<mat-form-field>` placeholder text ("Search for your school...") is too low near the bottom of the `<input>` box. How can I vertically raise it so there is more spacing below the text? It should appear in the middle of the `<input>` box like the magnifying glass. I'm using Angular Material 7.

[image]

**HTML**

```
 <mat-form-field style="width: 50vw; max-width: 450px; margin-top: -4px;" appearance="fill">
     <input matInput placeholder="Search for your school..." aria-label="School" [matAutocomplete]="auto" (input)="filterSchools()" #schoolInput [(ngModel)]="searchModel" (keyup.enter)="searchButton(searchModel)" name="inputField" id="searchInput" (keyup)="keyuppedSearch()">
     <mat-icon class="searchIcon" matSuffix style="color: #6336c6;" (click)="searchButton(schoolInput.value)">search</mat-icon>
 </mat-form-field>
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fbcxc8?file=app%2Fform-field-appearance-example.html

**Solution**

After inspecting the `input` element, I added padding to the bottom of the placeholder using:

```
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-flex .mat-form-field-infix .mat-input-element {
  padding-bottom: 8px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you fork Stackblitz with that output?

Comment: What styles can you see being applied when you inspect using your browser dev tools.

Comment: I added the StackBlitz into the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The angular material for mat form field is by default designed that way. You can override the styles using the chrome dev tools and by copying the css selector for the fields and make the text align at center using CSS

Comment: Looking at the [documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview), the text for `filled` inputs is vertically centered within the `input` box.

Comment: Yes its by default . But you still change the styles for these . Use chrome dev tools and get the selector for it . in your case find and select mat-form-field input  something like this . inspect on the fields and you can change the styles to your need. if this is what you wanted to do mark this as an answer.